# nextProps keys mysteriously inaccessible though it has content

Tags: javascript, json, key, react-redux

I'm in componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) in a react-redux app

```
console.log("Debug NextProps: ",nextProps.variantCategories);
console.log("Debug NextProps: ",Object.keys(nextProps.variantCategories));
//nextProps.variantCategories[1] returns undefined             <-- I need to access this
```

I got an empty array for Object.keys and so I thought I might be accessing things wrongly and tested the same on a brand new object i,

```
let i={1: {key: "value"}};
console.log("Debug i: ",i);
console.log("Debug i: ",Object.keys(i));
```

And here's the console (expanded on the right column)

[image]

**What am I doing wrong?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I mutated the object before that the app started to react in such a strange and mysterious way!

And this can be found by checking console logs done before fetching data and those would retain values that are current values.

Answer (score 0):

What is most likely the case that you are seeing is that the property `1` is not enumerable, that is to say you are not allowed to access it in a traditional sense as a property.

The inspectors in most browsers nowadays reveal all aspects of a JavaScript Object in the console, but that doesn't mean your code will have the same permission or access to retrieve that data. To recreate the issue that appears to be happening, you can try this code snippet:

```js
var specialObject = Object.defineProperty({}, '1', {
    enumerable: false,
    value: 'some stuff here'
});

// console logging in an inspector would show the full contents
console.log(specialObject);
// prints: > Object {1: "some stuff here"}

// but trying to access the property as an enumerated value will not work:
console.log(Object.keys(specialObject));
// prints: > []
```

So the question I have - where is that data coming from? Seems like you were expecting a more plain object.

Comment: `nextProps` **is** looking like **exactly** what I want it to be _(similar to `i`)_, except for the fact that I'm not able to access its values through its keys; and when I access the same from inside of a React component through `this.props.variant[1]` it just works fine...

Comment: if it's being built as a specialObject as you've described above, how would I access the value at `1`?

Comment: I tried your code, and that `specialObject` behaves like `nextProps.variantCategories`, but then is there any test for `specialObject` maybe something like `isSpecialObject?` :D

Comment: I made `i` with data of `nextProps.variantCategories` still, there's a difference shown by console: Notice the difference in the collapsed form `i` prints as `Object {1: Object}` while `nextProps.variantCategories` prints as `Object {}`, why is that?

Comment: Plus, in `i` as specialObject, though keys are not enumerable, I **am** able to access `i[1]` but not `nextProps.variantCategories[1]`

Comment: Hmm hard to tell at this context, would need to see more of the overall flow of that object

Comment: Thanks for showing me a probable situation; I found that the object was mutated before I logged.